# Words associated with collecting money into a jar

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes you see people collecting money into a "jar" with a hole for coins in it. This may or may not be intended for charity (e.g. it could also be used by someone playing a guitarr on the street).

My question is: what is the everyday name of such a jar and what is the action of collecting money into it called? If you have more than one word propositions, please share.

Comment: Normal English would be "collecting in", not "collecting into". The psychology behind this being presumably the focus on the money in the jar rather than the act of putting it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`what is the everyday name of such a jar?`

Such a jar is called **money box**, **penny bank**, or **piggy bank**

`what is the action of collecting into it called?`

Action of collecting money for oneself  is called **savings** or **nest egg**.
Action of collecting money for others is called **fundraising**.
Action of collecting money from others for your performance is called **donation** or **tip** and such a jar is called **donation or tip** box.

nest egg: a fund of money accumulated as a reserve.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nest%20egg

Comment: Doesn't that have more to do with people saving money themselves? The case I'm interested in is where other people donate money.

Comment: @LukasKalinski updated my answer

Comment: Yes, but you can collect money from other people without the money being intended for charity. E.g. someone playing a guitarr, saving the earned money for himself.

Comment: Thanks! Do the jar names apply to fundraisning as well?

Comment: You just made the answer great, thanks, it really helps!

Comment: @LukasKalinski i have also answered your previous question on coin hitting other coins in a jar.

Comment: Google Translate is telling me such a jar is called a __collection box__.

Comment: @MrLister collection jar is generalised term.

Comment: @MrLister you can collect apples in that jar or money etc.

Comment: The action (if doing it for yourself) is called ’saving’. (verb)  savings and nest egg (both nouns) are what you have as a result of your saving.

Comment: Also, a donation or tip (nouns) is what they give you.  The verb donate is what the people are doing when they give you a donation.  They are tipping when they give you a tip.  What ***you*** are doing is *accepting* tips or donations or *collecting* them.

Answer (score 4):

In British English this would be called a '[Collecting Tin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/collecting-tin)' As per Collins Dictionary:

> a tin for donations of money for charity or another particular purpose
>
> *He found a coin in his pocket and slipped it into her collecting tin, helping himself to a scarlet poppy.*

You will note that it covers collections being made for non-charitable purposes as well as charitable.

Additionally, the terminology can still be used even if the collecting tin is plastic, as a [google image search for 'collecting tin' demonstrates](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22collecting%20tin%22&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB761GB761&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy9MCN6ZTdAhUHr6QKHXmmAuIQ_AUICigB&biw=783&bih=580).

However, someone 'busking', playing their guitar or other instrument on the street for money would be unlikely to use a tin. Traditionally they would use an upturned hat, but many musicians will leave their instrument case open for donations or have a small box or plastic bucket so that people can drop money in as they pass rather than having to push it through a slot. Such a box or bucket might still be metaphorically referred to as a 'hat', as in the phrase ['put out the hat'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22put%20out%20the%20hat%22&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB761GB761&ei=X-2HW7q4EoS8kwXq15ugAQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=872&bih=580).

Answer (score 0):

In the Midwestern U.S., we might refer to the "jar" as a "kitty" if it is being collected for a common purpose in a communal pot.  In our home, the "kitty" is the bucket of money used to take a Florida trip every few years.

http://www.saywhydoi.com/money-in-the-kitty-why-do-we-say-we-put-money-in-the-kitty/#comment-88722